# is it possible to pass argument during event bubble?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

For thie `HTML`:

```
<div id="a">
   <div id="b">
   </div>
</div>
```

when I click `b`, both of `a` and `b`'s `click` even handler will be triggered. My problem is, how can these two event handler communicate? e.g.

```
$('#b').bind('click', handlerB);
$('#a').bind('click', handlerA);
```

is is possible for `handlerA` to access variables in `handlerB`, or `handlerB` can pass variables to `handlerA` through the event object or something?

Comment: you can use a global variable perhaps

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That not only breaks the idea of event but also might not cover all your needs. E.g. you might need optionally prevent bubbling depending on some condition in *handler*B.

I suggest preventing the event bubbling from *handlerB* and call *handlerA* from *handlerB* explicitly.